# How do you extend the life of a collision motor?

Tags: collision

The object rotates with the string wrapping around it - but it ends at frame 250?

How do you extend the collision time to end at say, frame 350? So the string wraps around more?

[image: collision wrap]

Comment: If you use a simulation, i'd suggest to look in the **Cache** settings of the **Rigid Body World** (found under the **Scene Properties** panel) and adjust the End(the default value is 250).

Comment: I did that for the string and it worked fine - however there's no option for this with the cylinder. It only ends at frame 250 and I cannot extend it.

Comment: cylinder has a rigid body and collision

Comment: There seems to be an issue with the updating of the Rigid Body World, see [Rigid Body World cache broken](https://devtalk.blender.org/t/rigid-body-world-cache-broken-in-blender-2-8/6738/2), i guess you are victim to the same. Sadly i do not know the solution other then changing settings to force the update.